# Reducing Complexity finding the subarrays with a given sum

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to code a problem where I have to find contiguous sub-arrays of a given array with a given sum. What I am trying to do is use a loop i from 0 to n and another from i to n and compute all sub-array sums using this. But I think that time complexity of the solution can be reduced further. I just can't figure out how. Is the problem convertible to DP?
I need to find the total number of sub-arrays.

Comment: What if there are multiple sub-arrays. You want to find the longest of them? or all of them?

Comment: I need to find how many sub-arrays are there

Answer (score 1):

```
For positive numbers only
```

Initialize a variable `curr_sum` as first element. `curr_sum` indicates the `sum of current subarray`. Start from the second element and add all elements one by one to the `curr_sum`. If `curr_sum` becomes equal to `sum`, then print the solution. If `curr_sum` exceeds the `sum`, then remove trailing elements while `curr_sum` is greater than `sum`.

This algo will give the first correct answer. There might be more than one subarray present as answer. ``

Complexity : `O(n)`

Comment: What if negatived-valued elements are permitted?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I didn't take negative value in account. Will mention it in answer

Comment: @pcbabu It is O(n). check it. O(2n) is O(n)

Comment: This solution will work only for all positive array? A positive value may be added with least negative to all the terms.

Comment: Downvoters please explain. It works well for positive numbers atleast

Comment: @user1925758 Yeah, it will work perfectly for all positive array

Comment: +1, Looks good to me. I haven't tried though but it should work for positive integers. Complexity is good too.

Comment: @Owen: Because if there are -ve values, then removing elements is not the only way of reducing the running sum.

Comment: @user1925758 Yeah, it cannot be modified for negative numbers. Others have already mentioned it in the comments

Comment: Can hash-map be used for this problem. If yes, how?